# Recovery of unsaved Access 2013 module

Tags: vba, ms-access-2013

I was working on a new VBA module in Access 2013 when I received a `Your network access was interrupted. To continue close the database and then open it again.` error.  Careless me hadn't saved the module yet. After network access was restored, I closed the database hitting yes to save the module but I just received the same error again and the database closed.  Didn't even think to copy the code to a text editor before.  When I reopened the DB, the module was not there.

Based on some googling, it seems I am SOL. Does anyone know if there is a temp file somewhere containing the unsaved changes?

Comment: Alas, there is no temp file. The VBA is persisted in a system table, but only on a successful save. In the unlikely event that the VBA was partially saved, the act of reopening the database would likely have auto-purged the invalid VBA.

Comment: Thanks! That is what I was afraid of.  I've been spoiled by working in Excel VBA the last few months. Been years since I did anything in Access. I'll be more vigilant with the Ctrl-S.  Can't believe that Access can't recover from a network glitch.

Comment: To be fair, the contents of an Access database are a lot more complicated than those of an Excel file. I suggest: Never develop on a network folder, always on a local disk. Compile & Save often. Make regular backups (e.g. to the network folder).

Comment: @ThunderFrame: If you want to post that as an answer, I can mark it as accepted to close this question out. I ended up moving the file to a local folder (I was working in My Documents which is actually mirrored to a network share), rewriting the code with a lot of saves.